# How to replace the spaces in filenames with underscore

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

So im trying to rename all files in a directory, so that they do not have spaces. Im doing a bash script and im really not sure what to do, i've tried all kinds of quotes and escaping but im not sure what combo could work.

```
#!/bin/bash
#change empty spaces in filenames to underlineos
lsarray="$(echo "$(pwd)""/*")"
for i in $lsarray
do
    if [[ $i == *" "* ]] 
    then
        line=$(echo $i | sed 's/ \+/\_/g')
        j=$(echo $i | sed 's/ \+/\\ /g')
        mv "$j" "$line"
        echo "$i"
        echo "$j"
        echo "$line"
        fi
done
```

since mv needs "special variable expansion" im using double quotes on it. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: An easier solution might use `find . -type f -exec` in conjunction with `rename`.

Comment: The true word is underscore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore (I have edited)

Answer (score 8):

Into `bash` for all the files into folder.

```
for name in *; do mv "$name" "${name// /_}"; done
```

The `${name/pattern/replace}` replaces `pattern` to `replace` ([Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)). If pattern starts with `/` (here pattern is `/` + `Space`), it replaces all the occurencies.  Then `mv` renames file from `name` to new name with replaced spaces.

Answer (score 4):

With Perl's rename:

```
rename 'y/ /_/' *
```