# Potential issues (if any) in recursively replacing spaces with underscores across all filenames on hard-drive

Tags: shell-script, files, terminal, rename, filenames

In my external hard drive, there are about 1TB of data (PDFs, plain text docs, pictures, binary execuatables etc.). The data was created in Windows 10 and the hard-drive is formatted NTFS.

Starting from the root of the hard drive, I would like to recursively descend into each folder and replace the spaces in all files with underscore to make it easier to work with them from the terminal.

I saw the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321448/how-to-replace-the-spaces-in-filenames-with-underscore): and thinking of using the top answer there

```
 rename 'y/ /_/' *
```

from the root of my external hard drive.

However, that thread does not have a high view count and only 2 members have upvoted the answers. Being a novice, I am a little concerned if there might be any inherent issues in this. Is there a better way to handle this issue of cross-platform ease of working at the terminal ? (maybe advice like 'do this only for plain text files, or some other problems that I am not able to foresee')

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work for you, but stay alert for the following problems that may arise:

1. You may overwrite some files (ex: if you have '*some_file.txt*' and '*some file.txt*', the first one will be overwritten (lost).
2. The `rename` command is not recursive. If you have many directories and sub-directories, you will need to figure out a way to do it (script, or using find, as pointed by @centimane `find ./ -exec rename 'y/ /_/' {} \;`).
3. If you have some applications and lib files, they may stop work if they can't find the renamed files anymore (same for saved .html pages, for example).

   It is a good idea to try the command first in a sub directory with a copy of some of the files.

obs: Sorry about the English. It is not my native language...

Comment: I can help you with point #2: `find ./ -exec rename 'y/ /_/' {} \;`. You can see `man find` if you're wondering about the `-exec` syntax.

Comment: Good point. Find will be straightforward.